# How to Add GridView Columns Dynamically based on calender months

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

How can I add Gridview columns dynamically based on calender days? 
The header of the grid should show dates 01/01/2013, 02/01/2013...and each column is a TemplateField with a Dropdownlist

I achieved this for the weekly view since the fields are constant (7 fields) but when it comes to the month view I cannot add 30 or 31 fields because I've coded in ASP not on code behind C#.

Can anybody give me some hints on how to create a month calendar in this way?

I already tried these links but it didn't help

1. http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/08/03/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textbox-and-dropdownlist.aspx
2. http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/925328-how-display-selected-dates-database-calendar-control

Comment: Create TemplateField  upto 31 columns date not exceed 31days based on calendar hide TemplateField that is best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(System.Int32));
    dcol.AutoIncrement = true;
    dt.Columns.Add(dcol);

    int days = 0;
    string selected_month = "JAN";

    if (selected_month == "JAN" || selected_month == "MAR")
    { days = 31; }
    else if(selected_month == "APR")
    { days = 30; }

    for (int z = 1; z < days; z++)
    {
        dcol = new DataColumn(z.ToString(), typeof(System.String));
        dt.Columns.Add(dcol);
    }
```